# Given that at least two of the drawn balls have the same colour, what is the probability that all drawn balls are red.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am stuck on a very basic probability question and I can't see what I am doing wrong here.

From an urn containing a red, a blue, and a white ball, three balls are drawn with replacement. Consider the events:
$$A := \{ \text{All drawn balls are red}\} = \frac{1}{27}$$
$$B := \{ \text{At least two of the drawn balls have the same color}\}=\frac{18}{27}$$

Determine $P(A|B)$:

My attempt:

$$P(A|B) = \frac{P( A \cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{\frac{1}{27}}{\frac{18}{27}}= \frac{1}{18}$$

However, the correct answer is $\frac{1}{21}$. My understanding is that $P(A \cap B) = \frac{1}{27}$ because the only possible combination in which all drawn balls are red and at least two of the drawn balls are the same color is $Red, Red, Red = \frac{1}{27}$. Clearly my working is wrong but I can't see where I made the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a ball. It has any one of three colors. The probability that the next ball is a different color is $\frac{2}{3}.$ The probability that the third is different still is $\frac{1}{3}$. So the probability that all balls are *different* colors is $\frac{2}{9}$. Any other combination means *at least two* balls are of the *same* color. Therefore the probability of $B$ (that at least two are the same color) is: $$ \frac{7}{9}$$.

Therefore $ P(A|B)$ =  $\frac{\frac{1}{27}}{\frac{7}{9}}  = \frac{1}{21}$

Answer (score 1):

There are $6$ different combinations of balls that give you balls of $3$ different colors out of the $27$ possible combinations of draws without constraint.  Therefore, the probability that at least $2$ balls have the same color is $P(B)=\frac{21}{27}$, which isn't what you wrote.  (I suspect you forgot to include the three cases where all three draws result in balls of the same color.)  That's the source of your error.